# Two pjsua application at the same time on Android

Tags: android, voip, pjsip

I have two application, that uses pjsua. But I can not run both at the same time on a single android device. After running second application it crashes with exception:

> java.lang.Exception: Title:       pjsua_transport_create(type, &tcfg,
>   &tid) 06-26 14:49:56.355  Code:        120098 06-26 14:49:56.355 
>   Description: Address already in use 06-26 14:49:56.355  Location:
>   ../src/pjsua2/endpoint.cpp:1519 06-26 14:49:56.355  14:49:56.361
>   pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING 06-26
>   14:49:56.355  14:49:56.362 sip_endpoint.c  .Module
>   "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered 06-26 14:49:56.360 
>   28512-28512/com.lemondo.biz.intelphone I/System.out﹕ 14:49:56.363
>   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING 06-26
>   14:49:56.365   A/libc﹕ ../src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_acc.c:404:
>   pjsua_acc_add: assertion "pjsua_var.tpdata[0].data.ptr != ((void *)0)"
>   failed

Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set unique local ports (might be also described as bind ports in configuration) for these applications. For plain pjsua this is --local-port parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that is. When initialize org.pjsip.pjsua2.TransportConfig sipTpConfig = new TransportConfig(); sipTpConfig.setPort(SIP_PORT); SIP_PORT must be unique.

Comment: I am giving  two unique port numbers, It is working fine.My app in play store,If any voip app using same port,problem will come once again.How to solve?

Comment: You can retry pjsua_transport_create() (don't know what is pjsua2 equivalent) on error with other port or port = 0 for dynamic port. Either way may cause problems (e.g. if application is restarted and it registers again from another source port), so I suppose user should be informed to be able to resolve conflict manually.

Comment: @TMSZ : Thanks for response,I couldn't understand,Is there any way to creating a dynamic unique port, that is not used by the the any app in the device through code?

Comment: Assigning port = 0 (not sure if this is applies also to pjsua2 API, check documentation yourself) in transport config lets OS choose some semi-random available port (often in 10000+ range) for binding.

Comment: By setting SIP_PORT = 0 will working fine.Is the any problems will cause in feature?

Comment: After restart (unexpected restart, without unregistration in particular) port would probably change (although it can be mitigated by trying old port first and then fallback to 0/any) some registrars may deny registration until old registration would time out.

Answer (score 2):

just set sipTpConfig.setPort(0);
Set to 0, the system will automatically give a free port