# How to recover App crash when using same .so files in two projects?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using **example.so** file in one of my project(First Project),i was compiled and run the project in my device successfully,But i am using same .so file in another project(Second Project) and if i run the project it is forced close in my device

I found the problem, If i Uninstall the First Project The Second Project running without force close.

===> Is it not possible to run the two Projects in same device?

My log cat response is

```
    pid: 16631, tid: 16631, name: com.oneconnect  >>> com.oneconnect <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
    r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 00000180  r3 00000000
    r4 00000000  r5 be8e5e7c  r6 5edcde60  r7 5edcec14
    r8 00000194  r9 410fdc84  sl 41dee1b8  fp be8e5f04
    ip fffda808  sp be8e5e78  lr 4014554d  pc 40141be2  cpsr 60000030
    d0  64656c6961662022  d1  6a702f326175736f
    d2  546f7475615f676e  d3  4f74696d736e6120
    d4  6441203a726f7272  d5  6c61207373657264
    d6  6e69207964616572  d7  0155748065737520
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 4175574808000000  d17 3fe0000000000000
    d18 00000012410fdc48  d19 5ec4af845ef2c18e
    d20 6574726f70707553  d21 4000680000720064
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 be8e62ac00000000
    d24 00f500f500f500f5  d25 00a100a100a100a1
    d26 00a100a100a100a1  d27 00a100a100a100a1
    d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
    d30 0000000100000001  d31 0000000100000001
    scr 80000010
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 0001abe2  /system/lib/libc.so
    #01  pc 00018208  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #02  pc 00021ab9  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+60)
    #03  pc 00149af0  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so (pjsua_acc_add+284)
    #04  pc 00110d54  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so (pj::Account::create(pj::AccountConfig const&, bool)+100)
    stack:
    be8e5e38  00000000
    be8e5e3c  4164053a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-card-table (deleted)
    be8e5e40  4016f160  /system/lib/libc.so
    be8e5e44  5afafc70
    be8e5e48  4016f160  /system/lib/libc.so
    be8e5e4c  00000001
    be8e5e50  4016f254  /system/lib/libc.so
    be8e5e54  4016f1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
    be8e5e58  00000000
    be8e5e5c  4014554d  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
    be8e5e60  00000001
    be8e5e64  be8e5e7c  [stack]
    be8e5e68  5edcde60  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5e6c  5edcec14  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.19088)
    be8e5e70  df0027ad
    be8e5e74  00000000
    #00  be8e5e78  00000194
    be8e5e7c  fffffbdf
    be8e5e80  5edcddf4  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5e84  5edcde60  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5e88  5edcec14  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.19088)
    be8e5e8c  40144ab9  /system/lib/libc.so (fprintf+16)
    be8e5e90  4016f1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
    be8e5e94  40167ed1  /system/lib/libc.so
    be8e5e98  5edcddf4  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5e9c  4013f20c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
    #01  be8e5ea0  be8e5ea0  [stack]
    be8e5ea4  40148abd  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+64)
    #02  be8e5ea8  5edcec14  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.19088)
    be8e5eac  5edcde60  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5eb0  5edcde60  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5eb4  5edcde60  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5eb8  5ee11d64  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5ebc  5ee11d64  /data/app-lib/com.oneconnect-1/libmtapjsua2.so
    be8e5ec0  00000000
    be8e5ec4  410fdc9c
```

Your response will appreciated....

Comment: It should be possible. 1) "Force close" is not informative, you should provide the relevant part of the `adb logcat` output. 2) How do you install the .so? A market application and a device manufacturer one use different methods, plus hackers use installation scripts on rooted devices. 3) Does your library acquire system-wide resources? (In particular, the limited resource may be just memory.)

Comment: i am using different folder strct in libs armbi,armbi-v7 etc and different .so files

Comment: The backtrace shows that `pj::Account::create()` called `pjsua_acc_add()` and that function has executed an `__assert()`. The assertion has failed, and libc executed `abort()` that just jumped to the address 0xdeadbaad (pun intended by OS developers: dead & bad). I can guess that the assertion was about acquiring some shared resource. You need to find the problem in the source code of `pjsua_acc_add()`.

Comment: See this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071514/two-pjsua-application-at-the-same-time-on-android

Comment: @ user1846931: It is solved my problem,Thanks for response.